# NodeJS accesing html form file input

Tags: html, node.js, forms, input

I've been stuck on this for a while now. For some reason I can't get this to work. What I'm trying to do is get the name of downFile:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
 var selectedFile = req.body.downFile;
 var file = __dirname + '/uploads/' + filename;

  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

HTML:
[image]

If anyone knows how to properly get the name of "downFile" I would much appreciate.

Comment: from where you are getting filename  in `var file = __dirname + '/uploads/' + filename;` ?

Comment: By `name of "downFile"` do you mean the value of the input with `name="downFile"`?

Comment: I want "var selectedFile = req.body.downFile;" to return the value of downFile yes. When I use req.body.downFile it returns an undefined property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body.downFile` would work if you are passing the value of an input called `downFile` via `POST`. But since you are working with file uploads, `POST` won't help you a lot and should instead take a look at one of the following modules:

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req

> In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use a multipart-handling middleware like [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy), [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable), [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty), [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty), or [pez](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pez).